# Glass petri dish to replace plastic petri dish?

Tags: microbiology

I never use a glass petri dish before, but I just wonder if I can use it to replace for plastic petri dish because it can reusable. The only thing I worry is , in a Fridge's user manual, it said that do not put glass container into the freezer (usually -20 oC) because it can be damaged/break and even explode. So do a glass petri dish have any special design to prevent this damage?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Glass labware is usually made of [borosilicate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Borosilicate_glass) glass which is resistant to temperature changes, so putting a glass petri dish in a -20°C freezer should not be problematic, at least with respect to glass cracking because of temperature changes. I think the warning on your freezer is probably meant to warn against closed glass containers filled with liquid; as water freezes it expands and may mechanically break the glass, but for a petri dish is should not be an issue.

I would be more cautious about heat shocks with a -80°C freezer, though; in my experience at that temperature there is still a risk if the glass is not of good quality.

On a side note, depending on what you use the petri dish for, the [surface chemistry](https://www.sigmaaldrich.com/technical-documents/articles/biofiles/evolution-of-cell.html)  may be different from the polystyrene of plastic petri dishes, and if you are growing cells directly in contact with the surface, switching to glass may change their behavior.

Comment: Thank you very much. I'm not sure if it was borosilicate or not. Just found it on an online store and they don't provide much info. Let me try it myself.